# Meaning of Market Compared to Mall

Tags: word-choice

I had just come up with an Iraqi who was looking for a shopping mall where he can buy his shirts and clothings.

At first he had asked "where is the market?" So I had to re-ask him the category of merchandise he wants to buy.

I have a question here..

Does the word "market" also commonly include the place where you can imagine such as shopping mall complex? (Because where he was looking for was quite big multi-complex where we can watch a movie and shoppoing and eating.. etc)

Comment: Have you looked up a good dictionary?

Comment: This question is not about dictionary written but asking about the actual presence of word usage among the people in English conversation

Comment: You're quite right; dictionary definitions won't go into enough detail here. Malls tend to be bigger, newer, brasher, brighter; to have more upmarket eateries and shops, more chain-stores, fewer unenclosed establishments (stalls), and dedicated car-parks. Cinemas and other entertainment venues are much more likely to be found in malls. Of course, some markets are _outside markets_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the US, *market* has a very broad set of meanings. It may be a physical entity synonymous with "store" (in the physical retail sense), or it may be some theoretical concept such as "the market for older homes". *Mall* tends to be much more specific, and is a type of physical *shopping center* where the walkways are mostly enclosed (even though the very first "mall" in Chicago did not have enclosed walkways).

Of course, *mall* also is used to refer to an area, usually covered with grass or some pedestrian-friendly paving, that is in the center between buildings, etc. Thus the [National Mall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Mall) is the strip of land between the US Capitol building and the Lincoln Memorial.  (*Shopping mall* is obviously derived from this meaning, but has taken on its own meaning.)